# Create Reusable Button Component with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm having a `Nuxt.js` project where I'm using a custom button.

The button is a **link** with an **svg** **path** and a **span**. I also have animation for the button where it triggers on the **mouse over** and **mouse out event**.

here is my button code.

```
<template>  
        <a class="button green" href="/"
            @mouseover="buttonEnter"
            @mouseout="buttonLeave">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
                <path d="M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z"/>
            </svg>
            <span>Go Home</span>
        </a>
</template>


<script>
import { buttonEnter } from '~/assets/animate'
import { buttonleave } from '~/assets/animate'

export default {
    methods: {
        buttonEnter(event) {
            const buttonPath = event.currentTarget.querySelector('path')
            const buttonSpan = event.currentTarget.querySelector('span')
            buttonEnter(buttonPath, buttonSpan)
        },
        buttonLeave(event) {
            const buttonPath = event.currentTarget.querySelector('path')
            const buttonSpan = event.currentTarget.querySelector('span')
            buttonleave(buttonPath, buttonSpan)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I use this button in many pages and I feel like i duplicate my self and having a button component will make things better and more tidy. The problem is I'm new with Vue and I fail to do this. Can somebody **point me** out or give me an **example code** how properly to write a reusable component ?

here are also the buttonEnter and buttonleave function for the animation.

```
import anime from "animejs";

export function buttonEnter(buttonPath, buttonSpan) {
  anime.remove([buttonPath, buttonSpan]);
  anime({
    targets: buttonPath,
    d:
      "M10,10 C10,10 50,7 90,7 C130,7 170,10 170,10 C170,10 172,20 172,30 C172,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,53 90,53 C50,53 10,50 10,50 C10,50 8,40 8,30 C8,20 10,10 10,10 Z",
    elasticity: 700,
    offset: 0
  });
  anime({
    targets: buttonSpan,
    scale: 1.15,
    duration: 800,
    offset: 0
  });
}

export function buttonleave(buttonPath, buttonSpan) {
  anime.remove([buttonPath, buttonSpan]);
  anime({
    targets: buttonPath,
    d:
      "M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z",
    elasticity: 700,
    offset: 0
  });
  anime({
    targets: buttonSpan,
    scale: 1,
    duration: 800,
    offset: 0
  });
}
```

**here is a demo of the button** 
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/54jj5p3l9k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the content that you have in `index.vue` in new file named `custombtn.vue` under the `components` folder and your `index.vue` should be like :

```html
<template> 
  <div>
    test btn
    <custombtn />
    it done ! 
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import custombtn from '~/components/custombtn.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      custombtn
    }
  }
</script>
```

in `custombtn.vue` you could import `buttonEnter, buttonleave` as follows:

```
    import { buttonEnter, buttonleave } from '../assets/animate'
```

check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0oo7pk150w)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) is what you are after. Lucky you, this is really simple to do in Vue.js.

The only thing you need in your code is to name the component with the [name key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#name). For the example, let's call our reusable component custom-button: `name: 'custom-button'`

**custom-button.vue**

```html
<template>
        <a class="button green" href="/"
            @mouseover="buttonEnter"
            @mouseout="buttonLeave">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
                <path d="M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z"/>
            </svg>
            <span>Go Home</span>
        </a>
</template>


<script>
import { buttonEnter } from '~/assets/animate'
import { buttonleave } from '~/assets/animate'

export default {
    name: 'custom-button',
    methods: {
        buttonEnter(event) {
            const buttonPath = event.currentTarget.querySelector('path')
            const buttonSpan = event.currentTarget.querySelector('span')
            buttonEnter(buttonPath, buttonSpan)
        },
        buttonLeave(event) {
            const buttonPath = event.currentTarget.querySelector('path')
            const buttonSpan = event.currentTarget.querySelector('span')
            buttonleave(buttonPath, buttonSpan)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

The only thing you have to do now is to import the file in the page(s) you want to use it. Since we already exported it as default, we can simply import it using `import`. Last but not least, we need to tell Vue that we want to register a new component to be used in the markup. Add a components key with an object of components you wish to use on the specific page.

**about.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>About us</h1>
      <custom-button></custom-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import customButton from './pathToCustomButton.vue'
export default {
    name: 'about',
    components: { customButton }
}
</script>
```